# ORA-01722: invalid number after executing a select in Toad for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion

I have this select in TOAD for Oracle that returns ORA-01722: invalid number because of the select in then condition.

If I execute the select in then condition everything works, but if I execute the whole select i get ORA-01722: invalid number.

What i am doing wrong?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN f_man ('R', datos, ' ', 28) IN (SELECT cod
                                                 FROM groupss
                                                 WHERE cod in ('DT001', 'DT003'))
            THEN (SELECT DISTINCT replace (to_char(to_number(price)),'.',',')
                  FROM concepts p, criterias s, groupss g
                  WHERE     p.zone = s.zone
                  AND s.crt = 123456
                  AND p.year = '29991231'
                  AND p.concept = 'CC957'
                  AND cod = 'DT003')        
            ELSE '-' END AS IT
FROM criterias
WHERE crt = 123456
```

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of datatype is CRT?

Comment: It is number(6)

Comment: the problem is from replace (to_char(to_number(price)),'.',',')

Comment: So price is stored as a VARCHAR2 field?

Comment: price is number(17, 5), but i want to convert it into char

Comment: If `price` is a number, then `to_number(price)` makes no sense at all. `to_number()` expects a `varchar` as an argument, so `to_number(price)` will first convert `price` to a varchar just to convert it back to a number which it was to begin with.

Comment: i only wrote that because i got the invalid number error.

Comment: whatever i write there i get that error. I only want to replace the decimal separator, for example if i have 123.123 to return 123,123.

Comment: what happens if you simply use  `replace(price, '.' , ',')` ?

Comment: same error...don't know why

Comment: ``REPLACE(TO_CHAR(price,'.',','))`` might do the trick.